# PHP script returns "file_get_contents

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am building a site on my local Windows 8 dev machine(using wamp). I have a PHP script that is suppose to take image files from a directory on my server and upload them to a WordPress based website. When I have one file in the directory everything works fine. When I modify the code to upload multiple files from the directory, only one image is uploaded and I get an error saying: `file_get_content(/path/to/directory/): failed ot open stream. Permission denied in /path/to/script/` Here is an image of the error I am receiving https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6vnF.jpg

Here is the code that works with one file in the directory:

```
    global $post;

    $rpcurl = get_bloginfo('url') . "/xmlrpc.php";

    $username = 'admin';
    $password = 'admin';
    $blogid = $post->ID; //Post ID

    $post_idn = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'VIN', true);

    $post_dir = dirname( get_template_directory() ) . "/" . $post_idn;

    $file = file_get_contents( $post_dir . "/file.jpg");

    $filetype = "image/jpeg";

    $filename = "remote_filename.jpg";

    xmlrpc_set_type($file,'base64'); // <-- required!
    $params = array($blogid,$username,$password,
                array('name'=>$filename,'type'=>$filetype,'bits'=>$file,'overwrite'=>false));
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.uploadFile',$params);

    function go($request,$rpcurl){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$rpcurl);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$request );
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
    }

    $result = go($request,$rpcurl);
    print_r($result);
```

Here is the code that is suppose to upload multiple images.

```
    $rpcurl = get_bloginfo('url') . "/xmlrpc.php";

    echo $rpcurl; 

    $username = 'admin';
    $password = 'admin';
    $blogid = $post->ID; //Post ID

    echo $blogid;

    $post_idn = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'VIN', true);

    echo "<h1>" . $post_idn ."</h1>";

    $post_dir = dirname( get_template_directory() ) . "/" . $post_idn;

    $fileslist = scandir($post_dir);

    foreach ($fileslist as $file) {

        $file = file_get_contents( $post_dir . "/" . $file);

        $filetype = "image/jpeg";

        $filename = "remote_filename.jpg";

        xmlrpc_set_type($file,'base64'); // <-- required!
        $params = array($blogid,$username,$password,
                    array('name'=>$filename,'type'=>$filetype,'bits'=>$file,'overwrite'=>false));
        $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.uploadFile',$params);
    }

        function go($request,$rpcurl){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$rpcurl);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$request );
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
        }

        $result = go($request,$rpcurl);
        print_r($result);
```

Comment: Have you checked all the file permissions for the files in the directory?

Comment: File permissions are ok because it will upload the file named file.jpg but not any of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scandir` will return `.` and `..`, along with all real files and subdirectories](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php). You need to filter those out:

```
foreach ($fileslist as $file) {
    if( $file === '.' || $file === '..' ) {
        continue;
    }

    $file = file_get_contents( $post_dir . "/" . $file);

    $filetype = "image/jpeg";

    $filename = "remote_filename.jpg";

    xmlrpc_set_type($file,'base64'); // <-- required!
    $params = array($blogid,$username,$password,
                array('name'=>$filename,'type'=>$filetype,'bits'=>$file,'overwrite'=>false));
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.uploadFile',$params);
}
```

The tip-off here is the error message: `file_get_contents(/path/to/directory/): failed to open stream. Permission denied in /path/to/script/` If `$file` was a real file, you would see `/path/to/directory/somefile.extension`, not just `/path/to/directory/`.

Also, you are giving every uploaded file the same file name with this line: `$filename = "remote_filename.jpg";` So, no matter how many files are uploaded, only one is left at the end (the first one, because of `'overwrite'=>false`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually just noticed the "." and ".." were added. That did remove the errors but there is still only one file being uploaded. I guess that has something to do with the foreach statement.

Comment: See my last paragraph above (just added) -- you are giving every file the same name, so only one gets saved.